# add icons to powerpoint bullets that are dependent upon a column's value using R's officer package

Tags: r, alignment, r-markdown, powerpoint, officer

I'm trying to automate a PowerPoint report. In this report, I'll have a list of values and then a dichotomous indicator (good vs bad). When the report is generated, I want each value to have a happy face when the status is "good" and a frowning face when the status is "bad" and to be aligned with their respective text (see below image).

However, I can't figure out how to tell R how to do this. I tried making the data frame have an image column, but I couldn't get that to work. Now, I'm trying to just import the pngs directly into my slides using the officer page, but I'm not sure how to get them to line up with my text.

I've included an image of what I want the slide to look like. The code below reproduces everything except for adding the images to the plot.

```
library(png)
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)

#These line breaks are important for the spacing on the slide; please do not remove
mock_data <- tibble(status = c("Bad R Day", "Bad R Day", "Good R Day", "Bad R Day", "Good R Day"),
                    my_feelings = c("Ughh \n \n", "Why R?? \n \n", "R, you can do it all! \n \n", "Not again.. \n \n", "EUREKA! \n \n"))

#I don't know how to use readPNG to get web files, so I only have this one to show for this example.
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

#Make an empty slide
slide <- read_pptx()
slide <- add_slide(slide, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")

#Add in text properties and create specific text for slide
text_properties <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 14, font.family = "Arial")
text_content <- ftext(mock_data$my_feelings, text_properties)

#Make slide that has text in correct position
new_slide <- mock_data %>%
  ph_with(x = slide, value = fpar(text_content),
          location = ph_location(left = 6.45, top = 2.45))

#Print slide; adjust file path
print(new_slide, target = "your/filepath/here.pptx")
```

Note: I'm new to using the readPNG package, so I don't know how to make my reproducible example include 2 PNG files. If you can use another either from online or that just has the framework on how I would adapt it for 2 images, that would be really helpful. Also, for some reason, officer adds in a lot of whitespace that I cannot remove, even with trimws(). If you can't get that gone, then no worries[image]

EDIT:

This is one of the icons I'm trying to use:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom function `AddTextWithImage` positions one icon relatively to its associated text using [`ph_location`](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/ph_location.html).

`lapply` creates a list of such functions, shifting down the top position for each row of `mock_data`, and chosing the icon according to `status`.

Finally this list is reduced using [`freduce`](https://rdrr.io/cran/magrittr/man/freduce.html) which applies each function in the list to the slide:

```
    library(png)
    library(officer)
    library(tidyverse)

    #These line breaks are important for the spacing on the slide; please do not remove
    mock_data <- tibble(status = c("Bad R Day", "Bad R Day", "Good R Day", "Bad R Day", "Good R Day"),
                        my_feelings = c("Ughh \n \n", "Why R?? \n \n", "R, you can do it all! \n \n", "Not again.. \n \n", "EUREKA! \n \n"))

    #Make an empty slide
    slide <- read_pptx()
    slide <- add_slide(slide, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
    img.logo <- file.path( R.home("doc"), "html", "logo.jpg" )

    download.file("https://openmoji.org/php/download_from_github.php?emoji_hexcode=1F61E&emoji_variant=color","smiley.png",mode="wb")
    smiley <- "smiley.png"

    # Draw icon and associated text
    AddTextWithImage <- function(slide,
                                 position_left,
                                 position_top,
                                 text,
                                 img,
                                 tabwidth=0.5, # distance between icon and text
                                 textcolor = "black",
                                 font.size=14,
                                 font.family="Arial",
                                 height=0.3 # height of each row
                                 ) {
      text_properties <- fp_text(color = textcolor, font.size = font.size, font.family = font.family)
      text_content = ftext(text,text_properties)
      slide <- ph_with(slide,value = fpar(text_content), location = ph_location(left = position_left + tabwidth, top = position_top,height=height))
      ph_with(x = slide, external_img(img, width = height, height = height),
              location = ph_location(left = position_left, top = position_top,width =height,height=height), use_loc_size = FALSE )
    }

    height <- 0.3
    position_left <- 3
    position_top <- 1

    # Create a list of functions (one for each row of mock_data)
    l <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(mock_data)),function(l) {
      function(slide) {AddTextWithImage(slide,
                                        text = trimws(mock_data$my_feelings[l],'right'),
                                        img = ifelse(mock_data$status[l]=='Good R Day',img.logo,smiley),
                                        position_left = position_left,
                                        position_top = position_top + l * height,
                                        height = height)} }
      )

    # Apply the list of functions to the slide
    slide <- magrittr::freduce(slide,l)

    print(slide, target = "here.pptx")

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help! This code works, but for some reason, I get an error whenever I try to read in the image from my computer. How would I modify your code to read in a PNG (or, if need-be, a jpeg) from my computer instead of downloading one? I've tried using readPNG with native to True (as well) as false, and I keep getting this error on the last line: Error in file.exists(src) : invalid 'file' argument. I've checked the file path many times, and I know it's right because I'm getting the template read in. If you can give a template code for this portion, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: I edited the post to include the icon that I'm using for one of the bullets. If you could save that to your desktop (or any icon) and then put something like "your/pathway/here", that would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: if you look in the working directory, you'll see that the internet download actually created a file called "smiley.png", which is then used. So if you put your own png file in the same directory, you should be able to use it as well. Use getwd() to be sure of wd location.

Comment: to avoid wd problems, in Rstudio I recommend creating a project so that all files belong to the same project directory structure.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I did getwd() and saw the correct location. I'm hesitant to make a project because I'm going to need to grab files from different locations and can't guarantee they'll all be in one place. I just tried doing "setwd() to the correct folder but still got the same error.

Comment: if you know the directory, use `file.path("path","file.png")` to be sure you get the correct syntax in any system.

Comment: Thank you! That was my issue--the line works when I do NOT use readPNG(). Instead, saving the png as an object with the file path works. For instance, instead of my_pic <- readPNG("path/to/file/img.png") the correct solution is my_pic <- file.path("path/to/file", "img.png"). THANK YOU @WALDI! You deserve this bounty.